# Looking for a linux backup tool multithreaded with encryption and good compression algorithm

Tags: linux, backup, compression, multithreading, open-source

I am looking for a linux backup tool to upgrade my backup strategy.

Today I do full backups everyday on Linux server (Ubuntu 20.04).
I prefer to backup data directly inside our VMs and send to another site (not at VMware vSphere level) to not be dependent of the virtualisation system (in order to be able to restart from any kind of servers with a Linux and LAMP&Co tools).

We have more than a million of files (csv, json, xlsx) and almost 1To of data.
Compressed, it is reduced to 100Go in 4 hours thanks to lbzip2 and its multithreaded structure.
It is starting to be too much space and time per night.
I want to make full backups during weekends and only incremental ones on weeknights.

I tried Dar and Duplicity but there are not multithreaded and Dar only uses Gz compression (Duplicity can do bz2 from GPG but only on a single thread).

My dreamed solution :

- multithreaded to save time
- encryption
- good compression (lbzip2 or equivalent) to reduce disk usage
- opensource software

Does anyone know a tool or a solution I could use to optimise our backups?

Comment: Is this commercial? Not opensource at all but take a serious look at Veeam, which integrates very nicely with VMware. (Happy customer. Not affiliated.)

Comment: https://github.com/restic/others

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would rather not depend on VMware to be free to restart on any kind of servers. Moreover, my provider (OVHcloud) offers Veam but limits this products to VMs with at max 2To which is not scalable.

Comment: thank you for the link

Answer (score 1):

[Restic](https://restic.net/) meets your requirements: it uses multiple threads, performs deduplication and encryption, supports compression to reduce storage requirements, and is open source.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. After testing Restic, the latest stable version does not support at all compression which is mandatory in my case.

Comment: I asked Restic team, it will not be released before the end of the year or next year (it is on unstable-branch). I cannot install this in production until it is stable. The rest seems to be promising. I am testing this to evaluate its performance.

Answer (score 0):

[©XSIBackup-App](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsibackup-app/files/) is indeed multithreaded. It can read and compress while writing data to the backend at the same time. It works over SSH and can easily saturate a 1 gbps NIC with a fairly new CPU.

It has a nice set of features:

- Block level deduplication.
- LZJB compression.
- Works over any SSH enabled host, both as the backup source or target.
- It's not open source but it's free to use without any limit in the number of files or the size of them.
- It doesn't offer encryption, but given that it works over SSH you just have to enable it on the file system.